# SQL Query Question about Values in Column

Tags: sql, teradata

I am in a new table and I want to know what to use for a query to determine what values are in a certain column. I use Teradata as my place to write scripts.

Understanding a little more about the exact thing I am looking for. So I have a column name with `ENTY_TYPE`. When I limit the query to 1,000 I am only getting a limited of numbers (e.g. `1,2,3`). I want to see the whole possible list that the table has for the column.

Does anyone how I can query all possible values for the column?

Comment: All values plus counts are returned by Gordon's query. But looking at 1000 rows is usually enough to get some understanding of the data. Try a sample to get random rows: `select * from tab sample 1000`. And there might be statistics for that table which also include lots of details: `help stats tab` shows the existing stats and `show stats values on tab.column` returns the details for a specific statistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `group by`:

```
select enty_type, count(*)
from t
group by enty_type
order by count(*) desc;
```